# Is there a non surjective map $SL_2(\mathbf Z[X]) \to SL_2(\mathbf Z[X]/I)$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Is there a quotient of $\mathbf Z[X]$ (the ring of integer polynomials) by an ideal $I$ such that the map
$$ SL_2(\mathbf Z[X]) \to SL_2(\mathbf Z[X]/I)  $$
is not onto?

One thing I know: one much choose $I$ such that there are elements of $SL_2(\mathbf Z[X]/I)$ that are not product of elementary matrices. 
For example, it is known that there are elements of $SL_2(\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}])$ as above. However, I think that the map $ SL_2(\mathbf Z[X]) \to SL_2(\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}])$ is onto.

Hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question in the literature which I post here in case it can help someone.

Namely, in the paper
"On the groups $SL_2(\mathbf Z[x])$ and $SL_2(k[x,y])$. Israel J. Math. 86 (1994), no. 1-3, 157–193" Grunewald, Mennicke and Vaserstein prove that the map:

$$ SL_2(\mathbf Z[X])→SL_2(\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-20}])$$
is not surjective.
More precisely, they show that the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
4\sqrt{-20}+21 & 6\sqrt{-20}-32 \cr 12 &4\sqrt{-20}-3 \end{bmatrix} $$
does not come from $SL_2(\mathbf Z[x])$.